# Cross compile CGO app on darwin for linux

Tags: linux, go, cross-compiling, darwin, cgo

I'm having issues trying to cross-compile a Go app on OS X to run on linux/amd64.  The app in question is using [libvips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=VIPS) via this [vips go package](https://github.com/DAddYE/vips).  As such, it is using CGO and needs to be compiled with CGO support.

I'm on Go 1.4 and running the following build command

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 go build`

but end up with a linker error

`ld: unknown option: --build-id=none
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I'm assuming I probably need to add some kind of `-ldflags` argument but am not sure.

Is it possible to cross-compile CGO apps in this manner yet, or do I need to do a native-build on the target system to avoid issues and headaches?

Comment: I don't have OSX but it looks like a bad ld version or something. I'd say it's easier to just fire up a vm (does qemu work on mac?) and do your compiling there.

Comment: Yeah, I can native compile via a VM fine, and, of course, that whole process can be automated.  I was just trying to fight through and see if I can just cross-compile it all in one go natively like I can with non-CGO golang programs

Comment: I'd try to see if you can get a newer/different version of clang and ld but maybe someone else will know better.

Comment: `--build-id` is a command line argument recognised by GNU ld (used on Linux), so it looks like you're using the Mac tool chain here.  You will likely need to install a Linux cross compiler toolchain to get this to work, but I've never done this on MacOS myself.

Comment: @cpjolicoeur is a bit late but maybe there are others who I can help. I always get this linker error when using clang on linux (natively) the solution (for me) was to overwrite `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to use gcc in this case.

Comment: https://github.com/karalabe/xgo while this requires containers and docker it is very easy to use

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [gonative](https://github.com/inconshreveable/gonative). this allows you to cross-compile cgo code (as long as you are just using the stdlib).

Another approach would be to compile the linux binary using docker.

Answer (score 0):

Fast-forwarding to 2022, using docker for cross-compiling CGO apps to other platforms is your best and cleanest choice. Build docker containers that contain the correct cross-platform compiler and C libraries. Here is how I [cross-compile my Cgo applications with Docker](https://dh1tw.de/2019/12/cross-compiling-golang-cgo-projects/). Here is the [repo with the dockerfiles](https://github.com/dh1tw/remoteAudio-xcompile).